# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el resultado de un procedimiento dinámico en una variable y ocupar ese resultado en otro procedimiento dinámico?

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedure

Tengo varias bases de datos y estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento almacenado dinámico en una sola base llamada "Conexion" que abarque todas para no estar creando un SP en cada base. Lo que quiero primero es crear un SP dinámico que obtenga el valor máximo + 1 de una columna pero el problema es que no se como guardar la variable OUTPUT para ocuparlo después en otro SP dinámico, aquí lo que he tratado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE valorMaximoSP @base NVARCHAR(MAX), @outPut INT OUTPUT AS
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @valorMaximo INT
            SET @valorMaximo = (SELECT MAX(CAST(' + @base + '.dbo.EstacionesCat.ES_NUES AS INT))+1 FROM ' + @base + '.dbo.EstacionesCat) '
            + @outPut + ' = @valorMaximo ' +
            'PRINT @valorMaximo'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Luego ocupo esto para guardar el valor del OUPUT pero me sale error de conversión:

```
DECLARE @outPut INT
EXEC ES_NUES_SP 'basePruebas', @outPut OUTPUT
PRINT @outPut
```

Lo que quiero con esto es guardar el valorMaximo que devuelve el valorMaximoSP en una variable dentro de otro SP dinamico para yo poder hacer insert a dos tablas, ya que el primer insert del siguiente SP agrega un nuevo valorMaximo, por ejemplo:

```
USE Conexion
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertarEstacion @base NVARCHAR(MAX), @Estacion NVARCHAR(MAX), @terminada BIT, @completa BIT, @especial BIT AS
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @BaseDatos NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DB NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @outPut INT
SET @BaseDatos = (SELECT base + '.dbo.EstacionesCat' FROM tablaPrueba WHERE base = @base)
EXEC ES_NUES_SP @base, @outPut OUTPUT
SET @DB = (SELECT base FROM BD_V2 WHERE base = @base)
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @BaseDatos + '(' + @BaseDatos + '.ES_NUES, ' + @BaseDatos + '.Estacion, ' + @BaseDatos + '.terminada, ' + @BaseDatos + '.completa, ' + @BaseDatos + '.especial, ' + @BaseDatos + '.especial, ' + @BaseDatos + '.clave) VALUES (' + @outPut + ', ' + @Estacion + ', ' + CAST(@TERMINADA AS CHAR(1)) + ', ' + CAST(@Completa AS CHAR(1)) + ', ' + CAST(@Especial AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
.
.
.
--Aquí va el segundo Insert dinamico que requiere del mismo valorMaximoSP anterior sin tener que poner -1

PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)

--PRINT @SQL2 
--EXEC (@SQL2) --2do insert
```

Gracias por cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás haciendo varias cosas mal. Para empezar, tu código está completamente abierto a inyección de SQL. Eso es uno de los principales problemas de seguridad. En segundo lugar, no toma en cuenta la posibilidad de que exista recurrencia y se asignen datos repetidos en la tabla. En tercer lugar, no es necesario separar las operaciones si todo es parte de un mismo proceso.

Para solucionar el primer problema usamos SQL dinámico parametrizado con el procedimiento especial `sp_executesql`. También usamos la función `QUOTENAME()` para agregar validaciones a los nombres de objetos.

Para solucionar los otros problemas, hacemos todo en una sola operación. El código podría quedar similar a esto.

```
USE Conexion
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertarEstacion 
    @base NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @Estacion NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @terminada BIT, 
    @completa BIT, 
    @especial BIT 
AS
DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Tabla  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Params NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @outPut INT;

SET @Tabla = (SELECT QUOTENAME( base) + '.dbo.EstacionesCat' 
            FROM tablaPrueba 
            WHERE base = @base);

SET @Params = N'@Estacion NVARCHAR(MAX), '
            + N'@terminada BIT, '
            + N'@completa BIT, '
            + N'@especial BIT'

SET @SQL = REPLACE( 
        'INSERT INTO ' + @Tabla + '(' 
            + 'ES_NUES, ' 
            + 'Estacion, ' 
            + 'terminada, ' 
            + 'completa, ' 
            + 'especial, ' 
            + 'especial, ' 
            + 'clave) '
        + 'VALUES ( ' 
            + '(SELECT MAX(CAST( ES_NUES AS INT))+1 FROM <<@Tabla>>) , ' 
            + '@Estacion, ' 
            + '@TERMINADA, ' 
            + '@Completa, ' 
            + '@Especial );', '<<@Tabla>>', QUOTENAME(@Tabla));

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL, 
                    @Params, 
                    @Estacion,
                    @terminada, 
                    @completa, 
                    @especial;
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono!